# Query a JSON column to extract the selected map in Array List of Mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-5.7, mysql-json

I'm using Mysql 5.7 and it has following data set.

```
mysql> select id, browser from events;

+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | browser                                                            |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | [{"price": "10.00", "tag": "60"}, {"price": "25.00", "tag": "20"}] |
|  2 | [{"price": "8.00", "tag": "10"}, {"price": "25.00", "tag": "20 "}] |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to extract only the following map out of this data set. (Not the whole array list)

```
{"price": "10.00", "tag": "60"}
```

I tried following command but provide an empty set.

```
mysql> select * from events where json_contains(browser->'$[*].price', json_object('price',"10.00"));
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Can someone explain me why it is not working or how to query the map contains **price =10.00** ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT browser,JSON_EXTRACT(browser,"$.price")
FROM events t
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(browser,"$.price")=10.00
```